# distance in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

W is closed and convex subset of Hilbert space $H$. Suppose $x\in H$, $x_0\in W$. I am trying to proof, that $d(x, W) = ||x-x_0||$ iff $\Re(<x-x_0, y-x_0>)\le 0$ for all $y\in W$.

Could anyone help me with that?

($\Re$ is the real part)

Comment: What do you mean with $\mathfrak R$? Do you have some kind of an ordering on your Hilbertspace for you to consider $x-x_0$ to be _greater_ than something?

Comment: I think he means the real part.

Comment: Yes, $\Re$ is the real part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my notes:

$$\forall z\in W:\ \|x-x_0\|\leq\|x-z\|$$
$$\iff\forall t\in[0,1]:\ \|x-x_0\|\leq\|x-(x_0+t(z-x_0))\|$$
$$\implies <x-x_0,x-x_0>\leq<x-x_0-t(z-x_0),x-x_0-t(z-x_0)>=$$
$$=<x-x_0,x-x_0>-2t\Re\{x-x_0,z-x_0\}+t^2<z-x_0,z-x_0>$$
$$\implies 2\Re<x-x_0,z-x_0>\leq t<z-x_0,z-x_0>$$
$$\forall z\in W:\ \Re<x-x_0,z-x_0>\leq0$$